# Hover dropdown stays active even after mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this script where I made it when you have a small screen you have to click, tap on mobile, to show the dropdown menu. Now it works on this screen size but on bigger sizes I don't want people having to click on shit I want it to be on hover.

This is my code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var open = false;

      if ($(window).width() > 767) {
          $(".dropdown").hover(
             function(){
                 $('ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
                 console.log('display block de nav HOVER');
             });
      }
     else {
         console.log('kleiner');

         $(".dropdown").click(
             function(){
                 if (open){
                     $('ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
                     console.log('display none de nav');
                 } else {
                 $('ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
                     console.log('display block de nav');
                 }

                 open = !open;

             });
        }
});
```

The html

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#typo-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        @if(Sentinel::guest())
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('auth.login') }}">Typografics Academy</a>
                        @elseif(Sentinel::inRole('user'))
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('user.dashboard') }}">Typografics Academy</a>
                        @elseif(Sentinel::inRole('admin') || Sentinel::inRole('super'))
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}">Typografics Academy</a>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="typo-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            @if(!Sentinel::guest())

                                @if(Sentinel::inRole('user'))
                                    <li {{ Request::is('/results*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('user.results') }}">Results</a></li>
                                @elseif(Sentinel::inRole('admin') || Sentinel::inRole('super'))
                                    <li {{ Request::is('admin/users*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('users.overview') }}">Gebruikers</a></li>
                                    <li {{ Request::is('admin/tests*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('tests.overview') }}" >Tests</a></li>
                                    <li {{ Request::is('admin/profiles*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('profiles.overview') }}">Profielen</a></li>
                                    <li {{ Request::is('admin/results*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('results.overview') }}">Results</a></li>

                                    @if(Sentinel::inRole('super'))
                                        <li {{ Request::is('admin/questions*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('questions.overview') }}">Vragen</a></li>
                                        <li {{ Request::is('admin/categories*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('categories.overview') }}">{{trans('master.categories')}}</a></li>
                                        <li {{ Request::is('admin/companies*') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('companies.overview') }}">Bedrijven</a></li>
                                    @endif

                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nieuw <span class="caret"></span></a>

                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li {{ Request::is('admin/users/new') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('users.new') }}">{{trans('master.user')}}</a></li>
                                            <li {{ Request::is('admin/tests/new') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('tests.new.1') }}">{{trans('master.test')}}</a></li>
                                            <li {{ Request::is('admin/profiles/new') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('profiles.new') }}">{{trans('master.profile')}}</a></li>
                                            @if(Sentinel::inRole('super'))
                                                <li {{ Request::is('admin/questions/new') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('questions.new') }}">{{trans('master.question')}}</a></li>
                                                <li {{ Request::is('admin/categories/new') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('categories.new') }}">{{trans('master.category')}}</a></li>
                                                <li {{ Request::is('admin/subcategories/new') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('subcategories.new.without') }}">{{trans('master.subcategory')}}</a></li>
                                                <li {{ Request::is('admin/companies/new') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('companies.new') }}">{{trans('master.company')}}</a></li>
                                            @endif
                                        </ul>



                                    </li>


                                @endif
                             @endif
                        </ul>
                        @if(!Sentinel::guest())
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a class="userprofiel" href="#">{{ucwords(Sentinel::check()->first_name)}}</a></li>
                                <li><a class="logout" href="{{ route('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        @else
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li {{ Request::is('auth/login') ? 'class=active' : ''}}><a href="{{ route('auth.login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML for the specified dropdown

Comment: Is this a problem when you resize a window? It should not be the case on actual device. Try `window.onresize` event

Comment: @Pugazh The HTML is now added

Comment: @Morpheus When I go to the width of the device it works. But when i go Higher than the device width and my nav is normal not in a hamburger I can hover over it and my dropdown shows. But it does not go away anymore. When i try it with mouseenter and mouseout I can't target a link in the dropdown because I mouseout over the LI ITEM that triggers the dropdown.

Comment: @Surender Lohia answer should help you, the key is `jQuery method: .hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var open = false;

      if ($(window).width() > 767) {
          $(".dropdown").hover(
             function(){
                 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
                 console.log('display block de nav HOVER');
             }, function() {
               $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
             });
      }
     else {
         console.log('kleiner');

         $(".dropdown").click(
             function(){
                 if (open){
                     $('ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
                     console.log('display none de nav');
                 } else {
                 $('ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
                     console.log('display block de nav');
                 }

                 open = !open;

             });
        }
});
```

> Output: http://output.jsbin.com/wekepi
>
> Code: http://jsbin.com/wekepi/edit?js

jQuery method: `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`

> Ref: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're telling the menu to display as a block when you hover over it, it doesn't do anything else.

Add a class of `.block` and then toggleClass on hover, then it will add and remove as necessary.

```
.block { display:block; }


      $(".dropdown").hover(
         function(){
             $('ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('block');
             console.log('display block de nav HOVER');
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Surender Lohia I found the right solution for the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var open = false;

    var displayB = function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
        console.log('display BLOCK de nav HOVER');
    };

    var displayN = function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
        console.log('display NONE de nav HOVER');
    };
    var resizeEvent = function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $(".dropdown").hover(displayB, displayN);
        } else {
            console.log('kleiner');

            $('.dropdown').off();

            $(".dropdown").click(function () {
                if (open) {
                    displayN();
                } else {
                    displayB();
                }

                open = !open;

            });
        }
    };

    resizeEvent();

    $(window).resize(resizeEvent);

});
```